# SQL ORDER BY not working

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Get the latest 4 donations that come into the system .

Donation IDs are auto incremented (201 , 202, 203 , 204) .. therefore I wanted to order by DESC to get the latest 4 donations.

```
 $resultsdonations  = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM donationstable ORDER BY 'donation_id'  DESC LIMIT 0,4 ");
```

Comment: To add, in case you are going by example, you do not use the single quotes (`'`) but use the back tics (`\``) when dealing with field names

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the apostrophes around `'donation_id'` and the `0` is unnecessary in the `LIMIT` clause considering your requirement:

```
$resultsdonations = mysql_query(
   "SELECT * FROM donationstable ORDER BY donation_id DESC LIMIT 4");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$resultsdonations  = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM donationstable ORDER BY donation_id  DESC LIMIT 0,4 ");
```

(drop the ' around the donation_id column)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the quotes around `donation_id`. Just use `.. BY donation_id DE ..`

Answer (score 0):

As the other answers have pointed out, you must remove the quotes from around `donation_id`.

As it currently stands, you are not sorting by the *value* in the `donation_id` column, but rather by the *string literal* `'donation_id'`, which is constant for each record and therefore results in an indeterminate ordering.